# ogr2ogr can't find my layer's CRS

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm running the following command in an effort to convert the shapelayer in the screenshot below to valid WGS84 GeoJSON:

```
ogr2ogr mhp_ada.geojson -s_srs EPSG:102459 -t_srs EPSG:4326 mobiles.shp
```

And here's the error it is giving me:

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not found
ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: EPSG:102459
```

I've also tried using `-s_srs EPSG::2253` as the source CRS. That exports just fine, but the lon/lat are off by ~1000 miles.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Here's a screenshot of the shapefile successfully loaded into QGIS:

[image]

Comment: what does ogrinfo report for mhp_ada.geojson? verify that it is EPSG:102459 and valid. often the 'ESRI' CRS definitions do not play nicely. reproject to a non-ESRI CRS in QGIS before doing the translation.

Comment: @jamierob, thank you. I simply removed the 'source' in my `ogr2ogr` command and it worked: `ogr2ogr mhp_ada.geojson -t_srs EPSG:4326 mobiles.shp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the source in the `ogr2ogr` command and I am successfully converting to valid WGS84 GeoJSON.

`ogr2ogr mhp_ada.geojson -t_srs EPSG:4326`

Answer (score 1):

There's no EPSG code "102459".  However, ["102459" is an *ESRI* code](https://epsg.io/102459).

If your spatial reference is defined in your dataset, as you noted, you can leave out the `-s_srs` parameter and `ogr2ogr` will  get that info from the data.

If you need to specify the spatial reference (e.g. if it's not defined in the dataset), you can use `ESRI:102459` e.g.

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs ESRI:102459 -t_srs EPSG:4326 output.shp input.shp
```